# How to invoke methods on a remote connected server

Tags: python, server, remote-access, portability, remote-desktop

So i'm wondering if there's any way I could invoke methods on a remote server. For example, lets say that I connect as follows (note this is for example purposes)

```
import psutil
import socket
HOST = 'my address'
PORT = 9999
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
   sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
except Exception as e:
    print("Cannot connect to the server:", e)
print("Connected")
```

and if successfully connected to the server then run something like:

```
 print(psutil.disk_partitions())
 print(psutil.virtual_memory())
```

but the idea is that the system will invoke the commands on the remote connection, not the local machine. Wondering mainly because I was looking at ways of making a non-invasive quick-connect health checking program to monitor multiple servers without having pre-requisites installed on each server. please advise.

Comment: You need to either (a) write a server program that listens for commands over some protocol you come up with then executes them and returns the results, or (b) use some existing server like and talk its protocol.

Comment: The obvious one to use for (b) is `ssh`, since it's a server that's already installed and configured on most systems, has had a lot of thought put into security and usability, lets you run an arbitrary shell for any user you can authenticate as, etc. Of course to run _Python_ commands that way, you need to use the shell to start up a remote Python interpreter and feed it input (or write out a script and pass it to the remote Python interpreter).

Comment: but that would require that the communication program is running on each individual server right? I was trying to make a portable variant that doesn't require that.

Comment: You can't connect to a server at all unless it's running some server program for you to connect to. And you can't make that server program run arbitrary code for you unless it was specifically designed to run that code. If this weren't true, you could use every machine on the internet as your own private botnet. (Well, you probably couldn't, because millions of other people would already be using up all the resources on the internet to rickroll and goatse each other before you even got there…)

Comment: lol! good advice, I think you pointed me to the right direction. I am going to instead use Paramiko to feed the bash commands to the linux terminal!

Comment: Please mind that you can only run the bash commands and cannot run an psutil command over paramiko as psutil would not have been installed in the remote server